# Python - Probability

Tags: python, linear-regression, probability

I have the following dataset that is part of a bigger dataset but I isolated to make the calculation easier (the whole data has more than 200 rows but as a sample I selected the first 20 rows):

```
Length  CTR
0   3   0.20
1   4   0.22
2   3   0.09
3   3   0.16
4   2   0.04
5   10  0.64
6   3   0.14
7   3   0.13
8   2   0.01
9   4   0.21
10  1   0.00
11  2   0.02
12  2   0.01
13  3   0.01
14  4   0.16
15  3   0.09
16  1   0.01
17  2   0.09
18  3   0.02
19  6   0.63
```

My idea here is to calculate the probability to have a CTR of 5%, 10%, 20% and so on given the number of length (1, 2, 3...). I did a few tests with crosstab but I'm not sure if that is the right way to go. I also did a regression analysis

```
#Clicks and installs
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Build linear regression model using installs
# Split data into predictors X and output Y
predictors = ['length']
X1 = df_num[predictors]
y1 = df_num['CTR']

# Initialise and fit model
lm = LinearRegression()
model = lm.fit(X1, y1)

print(f'alpha = {model.intercept_}')
print(f'betas = {model.coef_}')

new_X = [[3]]
print({"Clicks":model.predict(new_X)})
```

But that only shows me what is the predict CTR given a certain length number.
So far I`ve made a heatmap with the correlation between all the variables that I had and those 02 were the ones that had the highest corr (0.72), if that information is any useful.
Does anybody know what could be the solution here?

thank you